# Issue syncing comments from Jira to Rally and vice versa

Tags: jira, rally, connector

I'm currently working with the [RallyJiraWIC](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/agile-development-and-management/rally-platform-ca-agile-central/rally/integrating-with-rally/rally-integrations/rally-jira-work-item-connector-wic.html) and am running into some problems syncing the comments from Jira to discussions in Rally.

I am using YAML for my config file, and added the following:

```
RelatedObjectLinkers:
    RallyAttachmentLinker:
    RallyJiraCommentLinker:
```

The attachments are syncing as expected, but the comments are not.

I have tried adding comments to the `FieldMapping` section of the config file, but this led to a list object containing the comment being mapped to the value in the connector, ultimately leading to the value being skipped over when pushing to Rally.